# Sending values via POST using Web Harvesting in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Quick question. When using the Web Harvesting feature of WSO2 DSS, how do I send parameters via POST to a service such as the one configured below:

```
<config>  
    <var-def name="someName">  
        <html-to-xml>  
            <http url="http://server.yoyodyne.com/service/entryPoint?doQuery=someValue&amp;someKey=anotherValue" method="post"/>  
        </html-to-xml>  
    </var-def>  
</config>
```

For example, if I wanted to send via POST the vars "firstField", "secondField", and "someFileName", where would I define those in the config? The documentation does not seem to cover this.

Comment: Anyone?... Anyone?... Bueller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment DSS only support simple HTTP Get and extract web data from given URL for Web scraping.

Regards,
Amani

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, though I was hoping I was just using the software incorrectly. Not being able to send a POST request is really going to limit the web scraper's usefulness in DSS.